# when to use --json-attributes option in knife bootstrap command

Tags: chef-infra

I have bootstrap a node using the --json-attributes, my JSON file does not contain some attributes, but after bootstrapping the node, node does contain additional attributes, I wonder from where this additional attributes come from.

```
 knife bootstrap --json-attributes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is used to set additional data on the node itself during creation. This is generally not considered a good idea as it encourages special-snowflake servers which are not easy to recreate. Try putting those attributes on a role or cookbook instead.